# How to convert videos to .GIF without photoshop on Mac

Tags: gif, mac

So, I want to make an animated profile picture for myself, but, I don't want to use other applications or 3 party software to convert it because of privacy reasons. Also, I don't have a windows computer, only mac. Please help me!

Comment: You don't want to use "other applications or 3rd party software"... so *what* do you want to use?

Comment: Is there NO other options? If there is none, please tell me the best way.

Comment: You say: "I don't have PS, but I don't want to use anything else" so *what* do you expect to use, if not something *else*?

Comment: I just want to know if there are any other options and what I could use. No matter what it is. (but photoshop)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking for a software list specific to an Operating System. This isn't really a design question.

Comment: I agree with WELZ, and almost with Scott.

In more than 30 years supporting Users, I've never once heard any suggestio that anyone working in graphics could even think about gettint by without Photoshop.

Could you please explaon why you're the exception?

Answer (score 3):

Drop to GIF (available at GitHUB) and GIF Brewery (Apple Store) both accomplish this task natively and locally on Mac OS without uploading anything anywhere. Drop to GIF is super lightweight and small footprint, but has few bells and whistles. GIF Brewery has a *lot* more features, but cost a small amount of money (I don't remember how much, but cheap) when I purchased.

If you use Screenflow (advanced screen capture and markup tool Mac OS specific) then know that this supports pretty advanced GIF export on its own.

And lastly, depending upon which version of the Mac OS you're running, on the latest, High Sierra, you *may not **need** any of these at **all***: Photos (newer replacement for older iPhoto) will export GIFs natively - from iPhone Live Photos or videos according to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [EZGIF](https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif) Video to GIF tool (they have many other awesome GIF tools)

It's **very** simple and easy to use it, that's why I prefer using it.

Just *Drag-n-Drop* you video into the "Choose File" box, and hit **Upload Video**

Then choose your options and convert - *wallah*, it's all good.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be not wanting to use "3rd party" stuff due to privacy... 
Most "free web video to gif" things will require you to upload the video.

You might try the suggestions [from this article at macworld.co.uk](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-make-gifs-on-mac-3517187/)

The article details how to use the iPhone, and also provides some Mac-based applications for creating animated GIFs.